# How to use KeyboardAvoidingView in an animation view in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I try to animate a login view with fly-in animation when the view did mount, but it seems that KeyboardAvoidingView isn't work inside the animation view. I have tried several packages, none of them work. Can someone tell me how to avoid text input behind the keyboard in the animation view?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue

Comment: try to run in real devices, it didn't work in the emulator